# chef-server-ctl command not found

Tags: ubuntu, chef

I've installed the Chef server on Ubuntu Server 14.04.  After downloading the Chef package (chef_11.12.8-2_amd64.deb) I ran `sudo dpkg -i chef_11.12.8-2_amd64.deb`.

```
The package seems to have installed properly.  The output was:
(Reading database ... 62460 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack chef_11.12.8-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chef (11.12.8-2) over (11.12.8-2) ...
Setting up chef (11.12.8-2) ...
Thank you for installing Chef!
```

When I go to the next step which is `sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure` it tells me that chef-server-ctl cannot be found. I assume that there is nothing that I should be doing to make the chef-server-ctl utility available.

Don't worry about being too obvious with an answer.  I'm a Windows Developer, not a Linux sysadmin so there might be something very simple that I'm missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you have accidentally downloaded and installed the client package, which does not include that particular binary. The server .deb files are named in the format chef-server_version_arch.deb.

I was trying to recreate your problem and accidentally did the same thing. If you go to http://www.getchef.com/chef/install/ be sure to select the chef server tab. It doesn't seem to stand out.